# Linq using case

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, select, c#-4.0

I want to apply condition on TableType.

```
If t.TableName='limit' then TabeType should be A_TypeTable
If t.TableName='health' then TabeType should be B_TypePolicy
If t.TableName='waiting' then TabeType should be C_TypeTable
```

Below is the query. I am not sure where to assign the case statement.

```
 var query = from a in tableA
                        join b in tableB on a.Hid equals b.Hid into ab
                        select new
                        {

                            TableType= ab.Select(t=>t.TableName).FirstOrDefault(),
                            UserName = a.UserName,
                            Description = a.Description,
                            ImportedDate =   a.ImportedDate

                        };
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this using ternary operator it convert condition to CASE in SQL.

```
var query = from a in tableA
                                join b in tableB on a.Hid equals b.Hid into ab
                                let x= ab.Select(t => t.TableName).FirstOrDefault()
                                select new
                                {

                                    TableType = x.equal("limit")? "A_TypeTable" : 
                                                x.equal("health") ? "B_TypeTable":
                                                "C_TypeTable",
                                    UserName = a.UserName,
                                    Description = a.Description,
                                    ImportedDate = a.ImportedDate

                                };
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be a workaround, but you can make a try, Create a method which will accept table name as string and return table type as string, the signature of the method will be like this :

```
public string GetTableType(string tableName)
{
    switch (tableName)
    {
        case "limit":
            return "A_TypeTable";
        case "health":
            return "B_TypePolicy";                  
        default:
            return "C_TypeTable";
    }

}
```

And you can call the method from your query like this:

```
var query = from a in tableA
                    join b in tableB on a.Hid equals b.Hid into ab
                    select new
                    {
                        // Here is the call
                        TableType= ab.Select(t=>GetTableType(t.TableName)).FirstOrDefault(),
                        UserName = a.UserName,
                        Description = a.Description,
                        ImportedDate =   a.ImportedDate

                    };
```